# Replace image in DIV on Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am writing an application in PhoneGap and I need to create a function:

After clicking on the PLAY button, in the DIV appears one image and after 3 seconds it automatically changes to another image.

```
<div id="imgtrening">
      <div class="cw1a" style="display: none" ><img style="width:100%"; src="images/cw1a.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="cw1b" style="display: none" ><img style="width:100%"; src="images/cw1b.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

And after clicking to the button id="play":

```
document.getElementById('play').onclick = function() {
     $('.cw1a').css('display', 'block')
     sleep(3000);
     $('.cw1a').css('display', 'none')
     $('.cw1b').css('display', 'block')
};
```

Unfortunately, my application waits 3 seconds and shows the second image (I do not see animation effect) (sleep is another function waiting 3000 milliseconds) :(

Comment: Making your code wait 3000 ms is rarely a good idea, you're better off using setTimeout(function(){$('.cw1a').css('display', 'none'); $('.cw1b').css('display', 'block')}, 3000);

Answer (score 0):

That's because `.css('display', 'block')` or `.css('display', 'none')` doesn't animate.

Use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).